# Sample camera images as bitmap Android

Tags: android, camera, face-detection, android-camera

I am trying to create an app which periodically samples an image in the camera(preview?) and then does some processing on this image (i.e. face detection). I think this is the way to go about this., I have looked into OpenCV but don't think my knowledge is quite up to scratch to get it implemented well enough. My idea is to sample the image (raw format?), convert this to a bitmap image which then a FaceDetector object can detect the faces in the image and indicate this on screen.

Very much like the Native Camera app on the HTC Desire, which puts a grey square around the faces it sees before taking the picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sam,

A sample is provided for capturing the preview stream from the camera: [CameraPreview](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/CameraPreview.html)

This would be a great place to start.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have something similar to this already. To display a preview on a surface view. I need a way of getting a snapshot of the preview for processing at a set time interval.